# Amazon Dynamodb Persistence model for .Net

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, persistence

In my table there is Global Secondary Index and i want to get the data from that index and filter them with another field. i want to do this by using persistence model. and that must be asynchronous.

GSI - patient id
other filter field - date.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer

```
            var context = CommonUtils.Instance.DynamoDBContext;
            PatientAppointmentObjectList.Clear();
            QueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilter();
            queryFilter.AddCondition("PatientId", QueryOperator.Equal, patientID);
            queryFilter.AddCondition("NumericAppointmentDate", QueryOperator.Equal, appointmentDate);
            QueryOperationConfig queryConfig = new QueryOperationConfig
            {
                Filter = queryFilter,
                Limit = 1,
                IndexName = DBConstants.APPOINTMENT_PATIENTID_GSI
            };
            AsyncSearch<ScheduledAppointment> appQuery = context.FromQueryAsync<ScheduledAppointment>(queryConfig, null);
            IEnumerable<ScheduledAppointment> appList = await appQuery.GetRemainingAsync();
            appList.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(i => PatientAppointmentObjectList.Add(i));
```